# Check two timestamps with current date in PHP (Laravel)

Tags: php, laravel

I have two timestamps starting_date and ending_date and I need to compare with current time.

I want to do something like this:

```
 $discount_db = Discount::whereActive(1)
                        ->where('starting_date', '<=', $curdate)
                        ->where('ending_date', '>=', $curdate)
                        ->first();
```

And I want to check this variable. I have an if where I have to check the timestamps, commands and other..

Comment: what do want in this?

Comment: Sounds good. What problem are you having with it?

Comment: You might want to let MySQL handles its inner date using its proper `NOW()` function. Use it like following : `->where('starting_date', '<=', 'NOW()')->where('ending_date', '>=', 'NOW()')`

Comment: Ok and how I can check in my if? if($var) ??? or I need to check the length with count?

Comment: Yeah, you can either do `if($discount_db)` or you can get the count by replacing `first()` with `count()`

Comment: I did it, but always is going on the else...and the condition on WHERE are good..

Comment: if is with two option..."good" or "null"..and it returns me always "null"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Carbon

```
 $curdate = Carbon::now();
 $discount_db = Discount::whereActive(1)
                        ->where('starting_date', '<=', $curdate)
                        ->where('ending_date', '>=', $curdate)
                        ->first();
if(count($discount_db)){ 
    //something happen here 
}else{
}
```

Comment: Understand this..I know how works this..but I don't know how to return on my condition if exist or not

Comment: `if(count($discount_db)){
    //something happen here
 }`

Comment: I did it, but always is going on the else...and the condition on WHERE are good

Comment: if with two option..."good" or "null"..and it returns me always "null"

Comment: what date format do you have in the ending_date, starting_date column? Maybe the whereActive condition is wrong, try just this: Discount::whereActive(1)->first();

Comment: it's not wrong..because exist in database and it's 1

Comment: no problem, a little code help: there is a ->whereBetween() function you can use like: `$model->whereBetween('date', ['2015-08-01', '2015-08-20'])->get();` have a nice day!